# "Can't load package" and "Use of internal package not allowed" when running goapp test

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When I run the command:

```
goapp test ./...
```

I get the errors:

```
can't load package: package github.com/projectname/oauth2: code in directory /Users/nyname/go/src/github.com/projectname/oauth2 expects import "github.com/projectname/oauth2"
can't load package: package github.com/projectname/oauth2/clientcredentials: code in directory /Users/nyname/go/src/github.com/projectname/oauth2/clientcredentials expects import "github.com/projectname/oauth2/clientcredentials"
can't load package: package github.com/projectname/oauth2/google: code in directory /Users/nyname/go/src/github.com/projectname/oauth2/google expects import "github.com/projectname/oauth2/google"
can't load package: package github.com/projectname/oauth2/jws: code in directory /Users/nyname/go/src/github.com/projectname/oauth2/jws expects import "github.com/projectname/oauth2/jws"
package github.com/projectname/oauth2/jwt
        imports github.com/projectname/oauth2/internal: use of internal package not allowed
```

It seems like no one else on my team get's this error.

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: go version go1.6.2 (appengine-1.9.40) darwin/amd64

Comment: Did you set your `$GOPATH` to `/Users/nyname/go/`?

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to have `$GOPATH` set the same as `$GOROOT`.

Comment: @KoalaYeung: $GOPATH is set to /Users/nyname/go (no ending slash). $GOROOT is not set to anything

Comment: Where did you install your go binary and the source (golang itself)?

Comment: @KoalaYeung: I have go_appengine in /Users/myname/. I have not installed golang separately from goapp as golang was included in goapp. I store my source code in /Users/nyname/go